# iOS back button working weirdly in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is something weird and happening randomly.

I am pushing a viewcontroller so by default ios adds the back button on the top left corner of the app.
Whenever user presses that back button it behaves very weirdly.
Attaching image of the same!

There is no way user can go back.It stops there(app doesn't hang)but back button stops working.
[image: Screen after clicking on back]
I am using following two lines to display a new ViewController.

```
    var vc=ShowNotificationController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I don't know why it is happening and it is happening very randomly.

We are using xcode 6.2 & swift

Comment: We will need some code here. Like... what are the ViewControllers concerned.

Comment: Need code for getting any idea.

Comment: Do you create navigationcontroller from codebase. I was faced same issue due to nested navigation controller

Comment: Provide us with your code that pushes this uiviewcontroller. there are several ways you can do this so without code no way for a solution!

Comment: I have updated the question with code.
@SantuC yes, I am pushing from code.I don't use storyboard at all.

Comment: Where are you calling the push code from? You need to give more context. Something to make sure of is that you are not pushing the new controller from functions like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` where the first controllers transition may not have finished. This can mess up the navigation bar.

Comment: I am calling it on response of an http call.So I guess it is completing all the function like viewDidLoad,viewWillAppear

Comment: @RushabhBhatt Is that HTTP response not in the main thread by any chance? If so then you have to schedule the UI updates onto the main thread.